# Why wont my window close after a period of time? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I can't figure out why the window won't close after 86 seconds.

Here's the code:

```
//Functions 
function URL() {
    return prompt("Enter the URL."); 
} 

function openNewWindow() { 
    var url = URL(); 
    popupWin = window.open(url, 'open_window', 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable,dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
    setTimeout(url,86000); 
} 

//Main
var url1 = openNewWindow();
```

Comment: I have researched this.. and tried multiple solutions. they don't work.

Comment: Why SHOULD the window close - you are not doing anything to close it. So all is as it should be (according to the code, you must express what you want in the code...).

Comment: i want the window to stay open, then after 86 seconds close automatically.

Comment: Not exactly related, but `window.URL` is a native host function/object in modern browsers, you shouldn't override it.

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that the code is *not* passing a function to `setTimeout`, but just a string read via `prompt`. (While setTimeout will accept a string, for legacy reasons, it must be valid JavaScript code to make any sense.)

```
function URL() {
    return prompt("Enter the URL."); 
} 

function openNewWindow() { 
    var url = URL();   // url is the RETURN VALUE of calling the URL function ..
    popupWin = window.open(url, 'open_window', 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable,dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
    // .. which is a string (representing a URL), not a function
    setTimeout(url,86000); 
}
```

Compare with:

```
function openNewWindow() { 
    var url = URL();   // url is the RETURN VALUE of calling the URL function ..
    var popupWin = window.open(url, 'open_window', 'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable,dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
    // .. but we pass a callback function :)
    setTimeout(function () {
        alert("done");
        // And assuming the browser allows this ..
        popupWin.close();
    }, 4 * 1000);
}
```

(Note that I've also made popupWin a `var` so that it is caught in the closure - thus all the opened windows should be closed after their respective timeout, not just the last one.)

Answer (score -1):

No where in that code does `window.close()` get called.

`setTimeout(url, 86000)` just schedules the execution of the function `url()` in about 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you, how exactly am i to call window.close() ?

Comment: 86,000 milli-seconds - that's 86 seconds. Where do you get the 24hrs from :)

Comment: yah, i was a bit confused about the 24 hours too

Comment: You're right, I'm in PHP world and `sleep()` today. 86 seconds makes a lot more sense... but yeah, you still need `window.close()` somewhere.